# Compile Error While Building MySQL connector from sources

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I'm building MySQL C connector 6.1.0 for my Visual Studio 10. It does compile fine for 32-bit after the following steps:

- Launch Visual Studio Command Prompt (as Administrator!).
- cmake . -G "Visual Studio 10"
- devenv libmysql.sln /build Release

for the debug:

- cmake . -G "Visual Studio 10" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
- devenv libmysql.sln /Rebuild Debug

But if I try to build it for 64-bit architecture using "cmake . -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" compiler fires an error:

```
11>my_atomic.c(30): error C2118: negative subscript
```

for the following line of code:

```
  compile_time_assert(sizeof(intptr) == sizeof(void *));
```

My intuition suggests, that the compiler didn't doesn't compile it for the 64-bit. Trying to pass such parameters to cmake doesn't help:

```
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-m64" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m64"
```

One more remark: the file "my_atomic.c" belongs to the project "mysys" and it is being compiled as C code (/TC option under Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own fault: for 64-bit have to run Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt !